# How to multi-select in a KendoComboBox, then cascade a child combo box with the multiple value selected

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I have to make my kendoComboBox to be able to select multiple items, then cascade the child combobox accordingly. let say i have a parent combobox named VehicleType and child combobox of VehicleBrand.

Selecting Car,Bikes, and Boats in the parent combobox will populate my child combobox with all the brands available.

Comment: [Good luck](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/cascadingcombobox)

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Challenge accepted